# How create Ajax Helpers in MVC3

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

i crate @Html.ActionLink helper here i check permissions of user. if yes i show this link otherwise not. now problem is with @Ajax.ActionLink can i make helper for Ajax.ActionLink? i make custom helpers to check permissions. it works fine with html.actionlink helper. How i check permissions in ajax actions ?

```
 public static IHtmlString CustomActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, int userId, string reqController, string reqAction,  string linkText,int reqActionId = 0)
    {

        bool isAllowed = checkPermission(userId, reqController, reqAction, reqActionId);
        if (isAllowed == false)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }
        return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, reqAction, new { id =reqActionId });
    }
```

i want to do this same check in Ajax Actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC HTML helper methods are just [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to the existing HtmlHelper and `AjaxHelper` classes. Once you understand what an *extension method* is in .NET and how it works, it's not that difficult to apply this concept to the `AjaxHelper` class:

```
public static IHtmlString CustomAjaxActionLink(
    this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper, 
    AjaxOptions ajaxOptions,
    int userId, 
    string reqController, 
    string reqAction,  
    string linkText,
    int reqActionId = 0
)
{
    bool isAllowed = checkPermission(userId, reqController, reqAction, reqActionId);
    if (!isAllowed)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }

    return ajaxHelper.ActionLink(
        linkText, 
        reqAction, 
        new { id = reqActionId }, 
        ajaxOptions
    );
}
```

And inside your view simply use this custom helper (after bringing the namespace into which the containing class is declared into scope of course):

```
@Ajax.CustomAjaxActionLink(
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "foo" },
    123,
    "SomeController",
    "SomeAction",
    "click me and get a surprise!",
    456
)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using AuthorizeAttribute?

```
public class AuthorizeAdminAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if(!AppSecurity.Instance.IsUserInRoles(filterContext.HttpContext.User, AdminGroups))
            {
                HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

and in your Controller you can use something like:

```
[AuthorizeAdmin]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```